# Change PHP error log to show local time instead of UTC

Tags: php, windows

Running PHP 5.4.14 on Windows Server and America/Los Angeles is set in php.ini for date.timezone yet errors print to the log wiht UTC time. Is there any way to have the log show current local time instead.

Comment: This probably has more to do with your web server. PHP typically doesn't write an error log but passes errors to the web server to handle logging.

Comment: Are you referring to PHP runtime errors?

Comment: Yes php error logging for bad queries, misseing semi-colons, requires etc..

Answer (score 0):

If these options are set in php.ini, PHP will log errors and warnings.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
error_log = C:\some folder\php_errors.log
```

This option (in the same file) will apply Los Angeles time instead of UTC to the timestamp of each logged entry.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```